# Make it constant?

Tags: java, android

I have the option to where users will email me, I just need to know how to make it so that the 'Subject' Of the email is always at a constant $1. And make it to where users cannot change the subject.

Below is my EmailActivity.java

```
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
    import android.content.ComponentName;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.Toast;


    public class EmailActivity extends Activity {

    Button buttonSend;
    EditText textTo;
    EditText textSubject;
    EditText textMessage;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.email_layout);

    buttonSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSend);
    textTo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextTo);
    textSubject = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextSubject);
    textMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextMessage);

    buttonSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String to = textTo.getText().toString();
            String subject = textSubject.getText().toString();
            String message = textMessage.getText().toString();

            Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{ to});
            //email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, new String[]{ to});
            //email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_BCC, new String[]{to});
            email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
            email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);

            //need this to prompts email client only
            email.setType("message/rfc822");

            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Choose an Email client :"));

        }
    });
}
```

}

And here is my xml file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewPhoneNo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="To : "
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextTo"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress" >

    <requestFocus />

    </EditText>

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewSubject"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Subject : "
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextSubject"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
    </EditText>

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewMessage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Message : "
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextMessage"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:lines="5" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonSend"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Send" />

   </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: If you don't intend for the user to edit the text, why not just use a ***TextView*** instead of an ***EditText***? Then just set the text to "$1" directly in the xml?

Comment: @sept Little things like this always fool me.

Comment: What do you mean? :O Was that the answer you were looking for?

Comment: @sept yeah man, been coding till 3 am every night so little things like that slip by me lol

Comment: I see. Okay. Will then just go ahead and add it as an answer. So that other users would see.

Comment: @sept The problem im facing is, after the users click send, I want it to automatically go to my email, know how to do this?

Comment: Do you already have an implementation with sending emails? I'm not familiar with it, but I suggest posting a separate question, if you can't seem to find any other posts or references searching in Google and here in StackOverflow. Just post the question, add the code snippets, and say what behavior you expect. I'm pretty sure a lot of users from the community would be happy to help you out. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since as you mentioned that you don't intent the users to edit the Subject, you can go on ahead and use a `TextView` instead of using an `EditText`. Just directly set the text value of the **Subject** there.

For more information regarding `TextView`s and `EditText`s, you can check out this links:

[TextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html)

[EditText](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html)